# Can I use modulecmd with fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish

At work we use the [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) package (and hence `modulecmd`) extensively.

[`man module`](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/module.html) includes the sentence “The sh, csh, tcsh, bash, ksh, and zsh shells are supported by modulecmd.”  This is confirmed by

```
hgs15624@pc0072 /d/w/c/m/m/mml> modulecmd fish load matlab
init.c(379):ERROR:109: Unknown shell type 'fish'
```

I don't really understand the why this is.  Which of `modulecmd` or `fish` would have to change?

I deduce from my experiments that I can't sensibly use `module` with `fish`.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Modules needs to be extended to support fish; none of the existing shells are close enough to easily apply to fish.

Comment: Added August 2016: http://modules.sourceforge.net/tcl/NEWS.html